# Book claims one can derive USCS mass unit "slug" from temperature equation shown in screen shots below

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, measurements, mathematics, energy

In the screenshots below, the author claims that one can derive the mass unit "slug" by somehow using the equation shown in the first picture. I understand how could derive a slug if you know that 1 lbf =  1 (32.174 lbm) ft/s^2, this as a matter of fact seems rather simple, but with this being said as well, why doesnt the author just show this method of reaching the value of a slug? and how does he employ equation 2, in screenshot 1, in reaching the value of a slug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A unit of mass is built into any measure of mass. Acceleration due to gravity (and the force required to prevent that acceleration) is just one way to measure mass.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Have you checked any of the many textbooks covering mass and acceleration? There are some very good ones even available on the internet as pdf.